# Increasing memory limit for mongodb aggregate jobs

Tags: mongodb, memory, aggregation-framework

Based on the aggregation pipeline docs, 
"any single aggregation operation consumes more than 10 percent of system RAM, the operation will produce an error."
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/

Is there any way of increasing this limit? I have also set allowDiskUse: true (so the error is no longer an issue), but would like to use more RAM to improve performance.

Background:
I am running a large aggregate job on mongodb on about 100 million entries. It is basically a massive call to $group to merge the entries based on a key.

I am using the dev release of mongo v 2.6.0-rc2 (3/21/2014)

Comment: I don't believe there is currently, you could try writing out to a collection that could "cheat" the limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well no there is no setting and if you really think about it there is good reason for this. So if you first consider what aggregate is doing and what MongoDB does in general it should become clear.

This is what *"should"* be at the "head" of any sensible aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match:{ /* Something here */ } },
```

And these are the reasons:

1. It makes **good sense** to *try* to reduce the working set that you are operating on in **any** operation.
2. This is also the **only** time you get the opportunity to use an index to aid in searching the selection. Which is **always** better than a collection scan.
3. Even though there is a built in *"optimizer"* that looks for such things as "projections" limiting the "selected" fields, the best scrutineer of working set size is to **only** work on the valid records. Later stage matches are not *"optimized"* in this way.(See point **1**)

The next thing to consider is the general behavior of MongoDB. So that the server process **wants** to do, is *"consume"* as **much** of the available machine memory as it can in order to hold the "working set" data ( collections and/or index ) in order to **"work"** on that data in the *most efficient means*.

So it **really is** in the *"best interests"* of the database engine to "spend" *most* of it's memory allocation in this way. As in that way, both your *"aggregate"* job and all of the *other* concurrent processes have access to the "working data" in the memory space.

So therefore it is *"not optimal"* for MongoDB to *"steal"* this memory allocation away from the other concurrent operations *just* to service your running aggregation operation.

In the *"programming to hardware requirements"* terms, well you are aware that future releases allow the aggregation pipeline to implement "disk use" in order to allow larger processing. You can always implement SSD's or other *fast* storage technologies. And of course *"10%"* of RAM is subjective to the amount of RAM that is installed in a system. So you can always *increase* that.

The roundup of this is, MongoDB has an actual **job** of being a *"concurrent datastore"* and does that well. What it **is not** is a *specific* "aggregation **job-runner**" and should not be treated as such.

So either *"break-up"* your workloads, or *increase* your hardware spec, or simply switch the large "task running" activity to something that **does** focus on the running job such as a *Hadoop-style* "mapReduce", and leave MongoDB to it's **job** of serving the data.

Or of course, change your design to simply *"pre-aggregate"* the required data somewhere **"on write"**.

As the saying goes, *"Horses for courses"*, or *use your tools for what they were **designed** for*.

Comment: For me this memory limit is quite arbitrary and hindersome. I run an aggregation on a DB with a large number of documents (expected to grow to ~450 million) and have to routinely run queries which return several million documents. This eats about 8GB of ram to run, so the 100MB is way too low and really just an arbitrary value.

Comment: _Please_, sir _"go easy"_ on the *emphasis*.  This _otherwise_ *"ok"* answer _hurts_ `my` _*eyes*_  ;)

Comment: While I agree that each tool has its job, the 100MB is indeed random and in some cases too low (why 100 and not 90? why 100 and not 200? each system is different). I see no particular reason not to allow someone to adjust the limit according to its needs. If there is a point where it may hurt other mongo features (don't see why it should be, but lets consider that) it can be specified in the specs. You can mount a drive in RAM and use that, or you can use faster ssds (that will not get near ram speed anyway). But *why* be forced to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 solutions I can think of:

Solution 1 (Mongodb):
[$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by id. Use $group only to count the amount of documents per unique id. Then use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) with [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) and [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/index.html) to split up the operation. I haven't done that, but I am about to try since I am experiencing the same problem as you.

Solution 1 (Mongodb):
Depending on the queries of your use case and the number of distinct id's you could create a collection for each id. It's ugly, but if each request is only targetting specific id's it might make sense.
Especially with a low number of id's there might be no other workaround since there is a hard limit to document size as well (16MB I think). A large enough document array nested inside a document is not an option I suppose.

Solution 3:
This solution would be writing your own highly customized database solution. Allocate memory, ideally a large sequential block. Lay out all the data it can carry in struct arrays within that buffer which can remain in memory at all times or be written back to a fast disk.

Perform most operations on memory in milliseconds time.

If the data is too large to keep it in memory for an entire operation, you can map files to memory and use views of those mapped files. I'm using 2 small NVME's in another project which cost me 40€ each. Together they can write 15GB to disk in less than 3 seconds which is the size of the buffer I need for the entire dataset.

I was convinced by a friend to give mongodb a try in order to scrape wildly variable data and am currently handling a 200MB collection which will eventually grow to 100 times that size. The operation I'm performing is simply grouping into documents by id and pushing the roots into an array. Allowdiskuse is set to true, but other than the wording of the error message this seems to make no difference.

I really don't see the issue with letting a user adjust the memory limit to his needs. Even if people will say using 16GB of memory is a bad idea, there are plenty of scenarios in which it definitely is not.
As adults we should all be allowed to make our own mistakes. No operation on a 200MB database should ever be an issue, especially not one as simple as the one I am performing - or failing to perform.