# Count only considers date and not time when aggregating in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Related question to get aggregate count has been answered below

[Count and Aggregate in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730518/count-and-aggregate-in-mongodb/26731299)

Query to do that is

```
db.sg_searchaudit.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$log" },
{"$match": {"log.ts": {"$gte": new Date("2014-09-01"), "$lte": new Date("2014-11-04")}}},
{"$group": {"_id": "$_id","count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
{"$sort": {"count":1}},
   {"$limit": 50}])
```

When i check the above query for a single keyword :-

```
db.sg_searchaudit.aggregate([
{"$match":{"_id": "mongo" ,"log.ts": {"$gte": new Date("2014-09-01T00:00:00.00Z"),     "$lte": new Date("2014-11-04T00:00:00.00Z")}}},
{"$unwind": "$log" },
{"$match": {"log.ts": {"$gte": new Date("2014-09-01T00:00:00.00Z"), "$lte": new Date("2014-11-04T00:00:00.00Z")}}},
{"$group": {"_id": "$_id","count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
{"$sort": {"count":-1}},
   {"$limit": 50}])
```

Tha is when i got to know that it actually aggregates for each date rather than aggregating over timestamp.

So the above query for "mongo" returns me **2** instead of **4** for below data.

```
{
"_id" : "mongo",
"log" : [
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2011-02-10T01:20:49Z"),
    "visitorId" : "25850661"
},
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-11-01T14:35:05Z"),
    "visitorId" : NumberLong(278571823)
},
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-11-01T14:37:56Z"),
    "visitorId" : NumberLong(0)
},
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-11-04T06:23:48Z"),
    "visitorId" : NumberLong(225200092)
},
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-11-04T06:25:44Z"),
    "visitorId" : NumberLong(225200092)
}
],
"uts" : ISODate("2014-11-04T06:25:43.740Z")
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Ah yes. The other dates are out of the range. If you want things on the "4th" then you do `"$lt": new Date("2014-11-05")` to the next day and not midnight on the current day.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I missed it while copying it over here. I have updated that in question. Still same result.

Comment: You are misreading the point. You are still using the wrong date. It's not a code issue. It's simply that the date is incorrect.

Comment: Ah .. ofcourse. I am sorry, misread your comment. Works fine. Thanks for your help :)